# Installation of more than one version of ns-2 on the same machine

Tags: ns2

I have an already working installation of NS 2.35 in my machine.
I need to install NS 2.27 on the same machine. My question is will there be a conflict between both versions that will make either of the installation to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all...
I have more than 6 version of ns2 on my Linux and there is no conflict between them.
It will work correctly.

You just have to install it in another directory.
For example:
If your current ns2.35 is in

`- $/home/ns2-allinone-2.35/`

you just have to create another directory for the other ns2, like:

`- $/home/ns2-allinone-2.27/`

Comment: I would suggest to use /opt/. And it is also common to create a ./ns/ directory and symlink it to the one you use most.